# media="print" external link does not work

Tags: css, printing, media, styling

I need to print my reports in a web application.

I have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />` in my code. But it does not apply any style. On the other hand, if I write **print.css** codes inside my document using `<style></style>` everything works fine.

What's the matter ?

Comment: does the browser in use accept media queries? BTW, here's a [good article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) for printing URL's in `print.css`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you insert print style sheet before main styles?

Comment: There is not any css before it

Comment: what you mean no css before? before print.css? It would be best if you gave us a link